# Why is there not a no-throw guarantee in the standard for std::set::extract() and std::set::insert(nh)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, splice, throws

In C++20 (N4849), there is no exception safety wording for associative containers' `extract()` and `insert(node_handle)`/`insert(hint, node_handle)` methods.

But for `merge()`, there is this wording though:

> Throws: Nothing unless the comparison object throws.

<sub>Location:
22.2.6 Associative containers [associative.reqmts]
Table 78: Associative container requirements (in addition to container) [tab:container.assoc.req]
Page 799</sub>

Apparently the orignal proposal ([P0083R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf)) intended to make it no-throw (page 5):

> **Exception safety**
>
> If the container’s Compare function is no-throw (which is very common), then removing a node, modifying it, and inserting it is no-throw unless modifying the value throws. And if modifying the value does throw, it does so outside of the containers involved.

But why is there no say in the proposed wording later in that proposal?

Comment: Note that unlike `merge()`, `extract()` has to copy the container's allocator.  But the Allocator model requires that copying be noexcept.  It does seem like `extract()` could be noexcept if the comparator is.

Answer (score 4):

The `insert` members taking a node handle have a precondition that the allocator in the node handle compares equal to the container's allocator.

The `extract` members taking an iterator have a precondition that the iterator is a valid dereferenceable iterator into the container.

The policy of the standard library is that functions with runtime preconditions are not `noexcept`.

The `extract` member taking a `key_type` argument can only throw if the comparison function throws, but that still means it can't be `noexcept`.

Comment: It's not about a `noexcept` specifier in the method signature. It's about a statement in the standard promising that no exception is allowed when certain preconditions are met. For example, the standard has this for `std::list::splice()`: "`void splice(const_iterator position, list& x, const_iterator i)`, *Preconditions*: `i` is a valid dereferenceable iterator of `x`. Throws: Nothing."(n4849 page 832, [list.ops]) For now no such statement exists for `set`/`map`'s `extract()`/`insert()` in the standard.